# D: call a function using a string variable with its name

Tags: d

D learner here...  if I have a string (value only known at runtime) that is the name of a function I want to call, how can I do that?  Example below...

```
void func001() {
//stuff
}

void func002() {
//stuff
}

// .........

void func100() {
//stuff
}

void main(char[][] args) {
  auto funcnum = to!uint(args[0]);
  auto funcname = format('func%03d', funcnum);
  ///// need to run the function named 'funcname' here
}
```

Comment: That `char[][]` should be `string[]` in modern D btw.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Hmm, I'm sure you're right, but they still have it marked as char[][] on the [D website](http://dlang.org/overview.html)

Comment: ah yeah, old page that didn't get updated. https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dlang.org/pull/1065

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example using compile time reflection. With `__traits(allMembers)`, we can loop through the names of all members in an aggregate (module, struct, class, etc.) and with `__traits(getMember)`, we can fetch a member by name and do stuff like call it.

The tricky part is `getMember` requires a compile time string, so we can't just pass it the command line argument directly. Instead, we build a `switch` to dispatch from the argument - almost just like you would by hand, but instead of writing all the names yourself, you let the loop handle it.

There's only two functions here, but it will scale to any number of them without needing to modify the `main` function.

See more comments inline:

```
import std.stdio;

// I'm grouping all the commands in a struct
// so it is easier to loop over them without
// other stuff getting in the way
struct Commands {
    // making them all static so we don't need to instantiate it
    // to call commands. This is often not the best way but it makes
    // for an easy demo and does work well a lot of the time.
    static:

    // Also assuming they all return void and have no arguments.
    // It is possible to handle other things, but it gets a lot
    // more involved. (I think my book example goes partially into
    // it, or something like my web.d goes all the way and generates
    // web/http and javascript/json apis from a full signature but that
    // code is pretty unreadable...)

    void func001() {
        writef("func001 called\n");
    }
    void func002() {
        writef("func002 called\n");
    }
}

void main(string[] args) {
    if(args.length > 1)
    // we switch on the runtime value..
    // the label will be used below
    outer: switch(args[1]) {
        // then loop through the compile time options to build
        // the cases. foreach with a compile time argument works
        // a bit differently than runtime - it is possible to build
        // switch cases with it.
        //
        // See also: http://dlang.org/traits.html#allMembers
        // and the sample chapter of my book
        foreach(memberName; __traits(allMembers, Commands)) {
            case memberName:
                // get the member by name with reflection,
                // and call it with the parenthesis at the end
                __traits(getMember, Commands, memberName)();

            // breaking from the labeled switch so we don't fallthrough
            // and also won't break the inner loop, which we don't want.
            break outer;
        }

        default: // default is required on most D switches
            writef("No such function, %s!\n", args[1]);
            break;
    }
    else { // insufficient args given
        writeln("Argument required. Options are:");
        // we can also loop to list names at runtime
        foreach(memberName; __traits(allMembers, Commands)) {
            writeln(memberName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat and well detailed, +1. I thought it'd be by far more complex than it in fact is.

Comment: The switch could also be final, then throwing an exception for an invalid function, which seem more appropriate for real-world application usage. Of course depending on how it's going to be used

Answer (score 6):

You can also use an associative array, assuming that each function matches the same prototype:

```
module test;
import std.format, std.stdio, std.conv;

void func001() {
    writeln(__FUNCTION__);
}

void func002() {
    writeln(__FUNCTION__);
}

alias Proto = void function();
Proto[string] funcs;

// assign the functions to a string in the static constructor
static this() {
    funcs["func001"] = &func001;
    funcs["func002"] = &func002;
}

void main(string[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2) return;
    //!\ note that first argument is always the application exename /!\\
    auto funcnum = to!uint(args[1]);
    auto funcname = format("func%03d", funcnum);

    // try to get the matching function pointer
    Proto* f = funcname in funcs;

    // call it if the function pointer is assigned
    if (f != null) (*f)(); 
}
```

Note that in your initial example you've made an error with the argument. `args[0]` is always set to the application exename. The first custom argument is actually `args[1]`.

The solution I propose will work if 1 or 2 is passed as argument and prints:

> test.func001
>
> test.func002

or nothing

Comment: Also note that `to!uint()` is not **nothrow**, so the convertion can be done in a **try..catch** statement. In case of failure you can assign a default value so that **funcname** is guaranteed not to be an array key.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going all wild with converting your string (parameter, runtime) into a function call ( which are mostly compiled ) and getting into intense memory/runtime/DLL stuff, you can just make a simple `if` statement.

Some pseudo for you, I'll happily translate it to D if you want me to -

```
Given functions func001, func002, func003:
 Read and store a string input
 if the input is equal to "func001":
  Call func001
 else if input is equal to "func002":
  Call func002
 else if the input is equal to "func003":
  Call func 003
 else
  Print "Not a valid function name. Available functions are func001, func002, and func003."
```

Comment: In D, you can also generate that chain automatically with compile time reflection.  The free sample chapter of my book goes into some detail with an example of how to do it: https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/d-cookbook but yeah this is the easiest way for a short list.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I see. It's good you state it out, because I'm no D pro, but the idea itself seemed to be way complex than it should be. Nice name.

Comment: Yeah, I could use a switch or if/else tree, but I was trying to get around hardcoding it, especially since there's going to be a *lot* of functions to choose from and the list may get very long.  I don't know anything about compile time reflection, but I'll check out @AdamD.Ruppe 's book.

Comment: I'll write you a short example in another answer too.

Comment: @J.R.Allen How long are we talking about? Because usually an if else tree would be by far more readable and simple - also probably more logical (which depends on the role of your program, but that's just my personal statisticless opinion). Although the second Adam seems to be an expert, I'm pretty sure his answer won't be easier to work with. Good luck regardless (:

Comment: Here's my example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993705/d-call-a-function-using-a-string-variable-with-its-name/31996526#31996526 if you strip the comments out, the main reflection generated loop is only six lines of code.... of course, it also simplifies the problem by assuming void returns and zero arguments. Handling them takes more work, but still you can do them too in about 20 more lines. Filtering different types of members is tricky though, that's why I put it all in a static struct for grouping. But still, it isn't too bad to read once you've seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking is most likely not what you ultimately want to do. I strongly recommend you read about the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) as that is most likely what you are trying to do.

PS. The Wikipedia article gives some complicated examples. In short, your Command objects can have names and you can easily have a map of Command objects, that you can lookup by name. The real power is that you do not have an enormous switch or something similar. Instead you simply pass a Command that you want to execute, and it knows exactly what to do.

If OOP approach is not good for you, then it is an exercise for you to come up with declarative solution.

It is, I believe, possible to define an user defined attribute (UDA) named, say, `command`,and use it to annotate every function you want to be treated as "command", and then you can use compile-time introspection like what Adam does in his example to setup everything so you can execute these functions when needed. You can have a map `CommandDelegate[string]` where CommandDelegate is simply `void delegate()` or similar...